# Search and replace regular expression in visual studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I have a bunch of code that I need to do a search and replace on to get it into the proper form for a new project.  I need to remove a prefix from a bunch of identifiers, but I don't want it to have any effect inside of a quoted string. For example if I have this code

```
#include "ABCmyfile.h"

class ABCmyclass
{
 ...
};
```

I would like the output to be

```
#include "ABCmyfile.h"

class myclass
{
  ...
}
```

I have to many different identifiers to search for, so I can't just do ABCmyclass -> myclass, because that would take too long.

In regular expression mode, in the search and replace dialog I tried to search for

```
~:q<ABC
```

and replace it with nothing, but that's not working.

Does anyone know of a search and replace regular expression that I could use to strip the prefix off of my identifiers?

Comment: I may be over-thinking this (or possibly under-thinking it), but I can't quite understand why a simple search for the string "ABCmyclass" and replace with "myclass" would take any longer than any other find/replace expression. Or, rather, why/how any other search expression would be any more efficient/beneficial.

Comment: I think there's ABCmyclass, ABCfoobar, ABCimawesome, ABCdracula...etc

Comment: @Greg - Yea, I can see not being able to search for "ABC," but if "ABCmyclass" is the only thing he's wanting to change he should be able to easily search for the whole string "ABCmyclass" and replace it with just "myclass" without affecting anything else.  But I may be mistaken, I over-think things sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you do it in three steps:

1. Replace `"ABC` with `"__PLACEHOLDER__`
2. Replace `ABC` with nothing
3. Replace `__PLACEHOLDER__` with `ABC`

Comment: This is close enough.  I can't always guarantee that the prefix is right after the quote, but there aren't that many special cases and I can take care of those manually.

Answer (score 1):

If the ABC prefix is always at the beginning of the quoted string, this could work for you:

Find what: 
  [^"]ABC

Replace with: (a space)

This changes

```
#include "ABCmyfile.h"

class ABCmyclass
{...};

class ABCfoobar
{...};

class ABCdracula
{...};
```

to

```
#include "ABCmyfile.h"

class myclass
{...};

class foobar
{...};

class dracula
{...};
```

How's that?

Answer (score 0):

If you can assume there's always a blank before your identifier, try searching for `{:Wh}~(")ABC` and replacing it with `\1`

Why won't `~:q<ABC`: work?

- I think it needs to be ~(:q), not ~:q
- :q matches a quoted string like "ABCmyfile.h", not a quote character
- < Seems to ignore quote characters